# SQL Case statements

Tags: sql-server-2008

update 1: here is my data looks like.

```
EmployeeId    EmployeeName    Active
12312         bob             0
23432         rob             1
32312         dan             0
43432         jan             1
.........................
.........................
```

UPDATE:

I am looking after something like this.

```
EmployeeId    EmployeeName    Active
12312         bob             active
23432         rob             pending
.........................
.........................
```

I am trying work around the following sql statement and its throwing me an error and not sure if this is the right way of doing...

//error:
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET'.

```
declare @currentStatus nvarchar(50)

Select EmployeeId,EmployeeName,Active,
       set @currentStatus = case when EmployeeId is not null and Active = 0 then "Active"  else "Pending" end as Status
from EmployeeTable
```

Comment: What are you intending to do with the @currentStatus variable? This would help in figuring out the best solution.

Comment: Just for clarity, CASE is an EXPRESSION that returns a value, not a STATEMENT (calling it a statement is what leads a lot of people to believe it can be used for control of flow, which it cannot). In any case you can't combine data retrieval and variable assignment in a single operation, not should you be enclosing strings in double quotes.

Comment: update my question, pls have a look.

Comment: Still don't understand why you need a variable. And if you have multiple rows coming back, which one does the variable hold?

Comment: @AaronBertrand: how should i do to get what i am looking for?

Comment: if you understand what i am looking for and you think my approach is not the best then would you sugguest me how to approach the problem?

Comment: Abu, what is it you are looking for and why do you need a variable?

Comment: @Abu I'm asking questions so I can get enough information to help solve your problem. I'm not doing it to be a pain; your question is terribly unclear.

Comment: well... i think i explained in my question what i am looking for but let me repeat again... the reason i am using variable to determine the status and as you see that i am check a condition and if that condition matches then displaying the status based on that.... so in nut shell i am looking for a way to display the status of an employee... i hope i answer your question.

Comment: Basically we're both saying forget about the variable and just use a single select statement as shown below.

Comment: @Abu try the queries that have been suggested to you instead of insisting that you need a variable. I think your assumptions about how queries are processed are incorrect.

Comment: i havent insist using the variables and in fact i have asked if there a better approach then mine. sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the results you show in your updated question, this is the only query you need. I have no idea why you think you need a local variable to hold the results of the case expression on each row.

```
SELECT 
  EmployeeId,
  EmployeeName,
  Active,
  [Status] = CASE WHEN EmployeeId IS NOT NULL AND Active = 0 
     THEN 'Active' 
     ELSE 'Pending' END
FROM dbo.EmployeeTable;
```

**EDIT** updated with sample data provided in question:

```
DECLARE @e TABLE(EmployeeID INT, EmployeeName VARCHAR(32), Active BIT);

INSERT @e VALUES
(12312,'bob',0),
(23432,'rob',1),
(32312,'dan',0),
(43432,'jan',1);

SELECT 
  EmployeeId,
  EmployeeName,
  Active,
  [Status] = CASE WHEN EmployeeId IS NOT NULL AND Active = 0 
     THEN 'Active' 
     ELSE 'Pending' END
FROM @e;
```

Results:

```
EmployeeId  EmployeeName  Active  Status
12312       bob           0       Active
23432       rob           1       Pending
32312       dan           0       Active
43432       jan           1       Pending
```

Comment: status is not a column name of the table and its a variable that sets...'pending' or 'approved'

Comment: @Abu you still haven't explained why you think you need a variable. Did you TRY my query? It adds status as a column in the result (your question said "Active" as the column header but I think you meant "Status").

Comment: yes i did try exaclty as you stated above... here is the error i am getting `Msg 141, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Line 83
A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.`

Comment: @Abu sorry, but that error message is not possible from the code I posted in my answer. You must still be using a variable for some reason. Please read this carefully: ***I DON'T THINK YOU NEED A VARIABLE AT ALL.*** Please try the code exactly as posted.

Comment: sorry...so i started with clean slate and i able to run the statement but the problem i see is that even though based on my data i have i should be getting mixed "Active" and "Pending" but in this case i am getting all the rows with "Pending" status? any thoughts?

Comment: Not without seeing your data, no.

Comment: @Abu I have updated my answer with proof that this works. If you can't get it to work, I don't know what else to tell you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try this:

```
SELECT EmployeeId, EmployeeName, CASE 
       WHEN (EmployeeId IS NOT NULL AND Active = 0) THEN 'Active' ELSE 'Pending' 
       END AS [Status]  
FROM EmployeeTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select EmployeeId,EmployeeName,Active,
       case when EmployeeId is not null and Active = 0 then 'Active'  else 'Pending' end as Status
from EmployeeTable
```

if you need to set the @CurrentStatus variable then you'll need to do that separately:

```
Set @currentStatus = case when EmployeeId is not null and Active = 0 then 'Active'  else 'Pending' end 
from EmployeeTable
```

Comment: hmm....i know it can be done seprately but the point here is that when i return the data i want that to display along with other columns not seprately....

Comment: What is the point of assigning it to a variable? Are you going to use the variable later? If so you're going to have to use two queries or assign ALL the columns to variables.

Comment: Why is running both statements a problem?

Comment: The first statement will return your table as shown at the top of your question

Comment: Except it still shouldn't be using `"double quotes"` for string delimiters. I get `Msg 207 - Invalid column name 'Active'.`

Comment: i was typing the sql statemetn in the question thread thats why i used double quotes and i am aware of that.

Comment: I think it was directed at me not you Abu - I should have corrected when I copied and pasted and I didn't.